# Access tables from different schema/user using DataMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, schema, jruby, datamapper

Currently I'm making a JRuby on Rails application access an Oracle database using DataMapper. I wonder if there's a config/routine to access tables from different users/schemas like:

```
SELECT * FROM "SCHEMAXY"."TABLEXY";
```

I've implemented a hack to make this work by specifying the schema together with the table name but I doubt this is a good soloution.

```
class Tablexy
  include DataMapper::Resource
  storage_names[:default] = "SCHEMAXY.TABLEXY"
end
```

**hack**(ish)

```
# Replace a dot in the name by a quoted one
# so "NAMESPACE.TABLE" gets "NAMESPACE"."TABLE"
module DataMapper
  module Adapters
    class OracleAdapter
      def quote_name(name)
          super.gsub('.', '"."')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I hope there is an integrated soloution for this in DataMapper.

Answer (score 1):

if you can execute a SQL `ALTER SESSION` command the following will work & allow you to use unqualified table names in `SCHEMAY`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=SCHEMAXY;
```

If that's not possible, you can create a `SYNONYM`:

```
CREATE SYNONYM TABLEY FOR SCHEMAY.TABLEY;
```